# Visible items only in selector always returns -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

(using jquery ui here)

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/2677/

Objective: When dragging any of the blue buttons, the other one should be hidden and I count previous instances of .user_task on the dom via index().

Without the :visible part in my selector, the code works as it should, I get the total items previous to the ones I click, with the addition of :visible in the selector it always returns -1.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    items: ".user_task",
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: true,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var taskid = ui.item.data("taskid");
        $("[data-taskid='" + taskid + "']").not(ui.helper).hide();

        var x = $(".user_task:visible").index(ui.item);
        $("#counter").text(x);
    },
});
```

My end result should be, drag last blue button and x=2 (for example)

Comment: why are you looking for the visible index? is there any specific logical need for this

Comment: See my comment on Rory's answer.

Comment: Irvin, that is only counting the visible elements in total, not the ones before the pressed item (if you start dragging 1 in your code x=4, it should be x=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nasty hack

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    items: ".user_task",
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: true,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        var taskid = ui.item.data("taskid");
        $("[data-taskid='" + taskid + "']").not(ui.helper).hide();

        var $usertasks = $(".user_task");
        var all = $usertasks.index(ui.item);
        var hidden = $usertasks.slice(0, all).not(':visible').length;
        var x = all - hidden;

        $("#counter").text(x);
    },
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bE2Sz/)

Comment: I still get the same result, when dragging "4" the result should be 2, it's still counting the hidden element.

Comment: I don't want to count ALL the visible elements, just the ones previous to the one I'm dragging.